# Flink - Stateful computation

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, stateful, apache-flink

I am struggling to find a solution on the following problem, using Apache Flink:

I have a stream of vectors, represented by files in a local folder. After a new text file is located using `DataStream<String> text = env.readFileStream(...)`, I transform (flatMap), the Input into a `SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>, ?>`, with the Integer being the score coming from a scoring function.

I want to persist a global HashMap containing the top-k vectors, using their scores. I approached the problem using a stateful transformation.

1. The first problem I have is that the HashMap retains per-sink data (so for each thread of workers, one HashMap of data). How can I make that a Global collection
2. Using Apache Spark, I made that possible by 
   `JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateDstream = tuples.updateStateByKey(updateFunction);`

and then making transformations on the `stateDstream`. Is there a way I can get the same functionality using FLink?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question has also been posted here: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Statefull-computation-td2494.html